# Using in-app billing in Application class

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

In my application I have one in-app product that can be purchased. This is a premium service unlocker for the application. Is it bad to check the purchase status in `onCreate` method in a class that extends `Application`?

The pros of this is that it can be done in the background and is not tied to an Activity. Currently, I have a splash screen and after that my second Activity starts which checks the purchase status. It is run in an `AsyncTask` which can take a while. Because of this, the user might see the premium version purchase button to flash.

I could do that in the splash screen Activity, but then I wouldn't have access to the connection and I can't bind the purchase action to a button in the main Activity.

This way I can also store the boolean value of the purchase state in the `Application` class. I need to access that from multiple places. Currently I am passing the value as `Intent` extra to the Activities that require it.

The only downside of this is that the connection would be alive for a long time. In my main Activity, I bind the connection in the `onCreate` method and unbind it in `onDestroy`. Does it keep an active connection open or is it okay to open the connection in the `Application` class?

Also, if the connection is opened in the class that extends `Application`, I have no access to any on destroy method to close the connection. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate%28%29), `onTerminate` in the `Application` class is never called so that user code is executed.

> It will never be called on a production Android device, where
>   processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including
>   this callback) is executed when doing so.

In my main Activity I currently have this

```
IInAppBillingService mService;
ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
};
```

In `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

In `onDestroy`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if(mService != null) {
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    }
}
```

And in the `onClickListener` of the purchase button

```
Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), "proversion", "inapp", "...");

PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
if(pendingIntent != null) {
    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), PURCHASE_RESULT_CODE, new Intent(), 0, 0, 0);
}
```